# Find parent id when all children share the same value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some data that looks a little like this

```
                 Table C
id | end_time
-------------
1    '2019-01-01'
2    '2020-01-01'    
3    '2019-07-01'    

                 Table F
id | parent_id
12 |    1
13 |    1

21 |    2
22 |    2

31 |    3
32 |    3
33 |    3
34 |    3



                  Table oui
rel_id | Product Version
1             '2'
12            '2'
13            '1'

2             '1'
21            '2'
22            '1'

3             '2'
31            '1'
32            '1'
33            '1'
34            '1'
```

Data relationship: 
c.id = f.parent_id

c.id or f.id = oui.rel_id

What I'm trying to find is where the rel_id for C in table oui is the parent's product version is 2, but ALL children are version 1.

I found a similar question over here: [Find ID of parent where all children exactly match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699160/find-id-of-parent-where-all-children-exactly-match) but couldn't quite adapt it to this use case.

Expected result:

```
c.id
----
 3
```

Reasoning: Both c.id 1/2 have children which have at least 1 item in product version 2.

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: Expected result in this case would be  3 since the children ID's for all the things in 3 are '1' whereas the others all have at least 1 number which is a 2 in the children

Comment: Sounds like a case for `NOT EXISTS` (child with version different from 1).

Comment: I wonder why there is a separate table OUI to hold the product versions. Why is the product version not a mere column in the tables C and F? Is the ID unique in OUI or can I find multiple product versions for one ID in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
select 
 t1.id 
 from c "t1" 
 inner join oui "t2" on t2.rel_id=t1.id 
 where t2.product_version='2' -- product_version for Parent
 and 
 (select 
 count(*) 
 from f "t3" 
 inner join oui t4 on t4.rel_id=t3.id 
 where t4.product_version !='1' -- product_version  for Child
 and t3.parent_id=t1.id
 )=0
```

**Note: Above query will work perfectly if the `ID` in table `C` and `ID` in table `F` is not same and `rel_id` column in table `oui` is having unique values.**

Comment: This more or less got me the right answer so I'm going to give you the correct checkbox on this one.

Answer (score 2):

Try this below logic-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=48493e8a4ded38f213b7349a11887c1d)

```
SELECT ID FROM C
WHERE ID NOT IN
(
    SELECT C.ID
    FROM C
    INNER JOIN F ON C.id = F.parent_id
    INNER JOIN oui ON F.ID = Oui.rel_id
    WHERE C.ID = CAST(oui.Product_Version AS INT)
    -- by default your column "Product Version" should be INT in table oui
)
```

The issue you mentioned in the below comment, you can try this opposite conversion as below-

```
SELECT ID FROM C
WHERE ID NOT IN
(
    SELECT C.ID
    FROM C
    INNER JOIN F ON C.id = F.parent_id
    INNER JOIN oui ON F.ID = Oui.rel_id
    WHERE CAST(C.ID AS VARCHAR) = oui.Product_Version
)
```

Comment: The data in rel_id is actually a complicated varchar value like "dvidhuv897t" and "123987vbkhj" so I can't just cast to int like this.  I simplified for the sake of making this easier.  There is no relation between C.ID and oui.Product_Version.

Comment: That case try the opposite way -     WHERE CAST(C.ID AS VARCHAR) = oui.Product_Version

Comment: @A_Elric please check y edited answer with new script.

Answer (score 2):

You want to get `C` entries with product version = 2 for which exists `F` entries with product version = 1 and not exist `F` entries with product version <> 1.

I don't know why there is a separate table `OUI` at all. One would expect the product version to be a mere column in the tables `C` and `F` instead.

So, let's use two with clauses to get to better tables :-)

```
with better_c as (select c.*, oui.product_version from c join oui on oui.rel_id = c.id)
   , better_f as (select f.*, oui.product_version from f join oui on oui.rel_id = f.id)
```

The real query can then be written with `INTERSECT` and `EXECPT`:

```
with ...
select id from better_c where product_version = 2
intersect
select parent_id from better_f where product_version = 1
except
select parent_id from better_f where product_version <> 1;
```

The same with `[NOT] EXISTS`:

```
with ...
select id 
from better_c 
where product_version = 2
and exists
 (select null from better_f where product_version = 1 and parent_id  = better_c.id)
and not exists
 (select parent_id from better_f where product_version <> 1 and parent_id  = better_c.id);
```

The same with `[NOT] IN`:

```
with ...
select id 
from better_c 
where product_version = 2
and id in (select parent_id from better_f where product_version = 1)
and id not in (select parent_id from better_f where product_version <> 1);
```